# IOS last tableViewCell separator is missing

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I have `tableView` with multiple cells (without sections).
I add non-empty `tableFooterView` to the tableView. After that the last cell separator is not shown. Also when `tableView` is scrolled, separator sometimes appears or disappears. It happens both on simulator and on the device.

I've checked *Debug view hierarchy* and found the following:
[image]

It is very strange. Penultimate cell separator is duplicated there but the last separator is single. May be the problem is somewhere there?

I've also checked it's properties:
[image]

All I found as solution is to add empty `tableFooterView` but I need it to be filled.

How to make the last separator be always visible (also when scrolling)?
I know you can get away without using actual separators, but adding one pixel line in the bottom of the cell. But I'm not a fan of this approach.

Comment: This is an interesting "bug" - and it appears it's been around for quite a while... I see references to it as far back as `iOS 7.1`. From quick testing, it appears that if the Footer View has a height greater than zero, it *replaces* the final separator view -- although, based on reports, it can "come and go" when scrolling in and out of view. Sounds like "fake separator" inside your cell is the only reliable solution. Or, adding a line at the top of your footer view, which might even give a better "look".

Comment: By the way --- kudos for the use of "Penultimate" :)